# Remote login and screen sharing to access Mac mini (M2) by MacBook Air (M1)

Tags: network, wifi, mac-mini, vpn, remote-desktop

### What I am trying to do

I have a Mac Mini in my office and am trying to remotely access it from home using my Macbook Air. When Mac Mini is always turned on and logged on, it is not a problem because I can use a VPN that uses my office network (Eduroam - if you are familiar with university wifi).

### Problem 1

But when my Mac Mini restarts after a power failure, it requires a log-in before connecting to Wifi. At this log-in stage, because my Mac Mini and my VPN-connected Macbook Air are not on the same network, I cannot use the screen-sharing function.
For screen sharing, I am referring to the YouTube video "[Remotely Control Any  Mac With Screen Sharing!Remote Mac Desktop with Remote Mac Access!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2YuwSXWJBI)"
What are your thoughts on working around this problem?

### Problem 2

Without using screen sharing, I tried to follow [How to Access and Control Your Mac Remotely from Any Device](https://www.macupdate.com/how-to/remote-access-control-mac) using the network. However, my Mac Mini is not listed in the Network view. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: If your Mac is not connected to WiFi because it needs a password, you’re not going to get around that problem, especially remotely.  Can you connect it to wired Ethernet instead?  How about getting a UPS to mitigate power outages?

Comment: Please note that this site works best with focus being on one issue per question.  That said, “Problem 2” is directly related to not being authenticated  to the network; same as problem 1

Comment: @Allan Thank you for your answer! I will consider connecting it to wired ethernet instead. Then, do you know what 'Remote login' means? What do I do with it when I allow it?

Comment: Remote login is SSH (Remote Terminal)

Comment: *"requires a log-in before connecting to Wifi"* You mean it requires credentials for the WiFi, or it requires a user to first physically login to the Mac itself?

Comment: @Tetsujin I meant the first physical login to the Mac. :)

Comment: Then you could set the Mac to auto-login, with a one minute drop to protected screen-saver.

Comment: Update: I ended up using VNC viewer from RealVNC! Using VNC viewer. I am not sure how it works exactly, but I could log in directly as long as my Mac mini was on. Plus, I set the Mac mini to restart automatically after power failure. I will still consider using UPS to protect my machine. Thank you all for your answers!!! It helped me learn a lot.

Comment: I recommend to use the [Apple Remote Desktop app](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/apple-remote-desktop/id409907375) on your Macbook Air instead of the Screen Sharing app shown in the video or even VNC Viewer. It's easier to use and much more versatile (and it's free).

Comment: @not2savvy Apple Remote Desktop costs 90€

Comment: @a06e You are right, I’m sorry. I’ve bought it many years ago and didn’t remember properly.

Comment: @not2savvy Do you still use it? Does it work well? I also have the OP problem and would like an Apple native solution

Comment: @a06e Yes, I use it all the time, and it works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> … when my Mac mini restarts after a power failure, it requires a log-in before connecting to WiFi

If the device is not connected to a network, you won’t be able to connect to it regardless of the service. There are two things you can do to address this:

- Connect to Ethernet. This is a more reliable connection and shouldn’t require password authentication.  However, it may require your IT department to activate the port or install a certificate on your computer.
- Get a UPS. You should have this anyway; protecting your computer from bad power is critical, but ensuring your computer doesn’t disconnect from WiFi during a power outage should mitigate the authentication issue

Comment: Update: I ended up using VNC viewer from RealVNC! Using VNC viewer. I am not sure how it works exactly, but I could log in directly as long as my Mac mini was on. Plus, I set the Mac mini to restart automatically after power failure. I will still consider using UPS to protect my machine.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!  I definitely encourage the use of a UPS; it's super cheap insurance!

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your problems might be due to active FileVault on your Mac Mini.

When FileVault is active, a local login is required to decrypt the boot disk and start macOS. Before the local login, the computer won't be accessible via Remote Desktop.

So unless you have a reason why you need FileVault, I recommend disabling it. After that, you should be able to remotely login even after a reboot.